# Failed to create a worklet. Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js

Tags: react-native

I just shifted my app from expo cli to react native cli, after shifting facing issue , getting component error and some other like below:-

```
Error: Failed to create a worklet. Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.j
```

I've already added to the babel config file.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin', 'nativewind/babel'],
};
```

Need some one help to fix this issue. and some other to.

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/#babel-plugin) say that the `react-native-reanimated/plugin` must be the *last* plugin listed in the plugins array in your `babel.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['nativewind/babel', 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'], // <-- switch these
};
```

After that, you'll want to clear your packager cache before restarting your app:

npm: `npm cache clean` (you may need the `--force` flag)

yarn: `yarn cache clean`

If clearing caches does not work, then you can try deleting your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` or `yarn install` again.

Failing that: downgrade or upgrade your version of `react-native-reanimated` to see if that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using expo so for me the command was `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Expo project I recommend to do it like this:

> babel.config.js

```
  module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
        },
      ],
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    ],
  };
};
```

Make sure you add react-native-reanimated/plugin as the last element of the plugins

Then stop the expo-server and run the following command:

```
expo r -c
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/ you are supposed to clear cache with `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. This solved my issue: Run the Following commands.
npm i react-native-reanimated

In babel config file:

```
plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
```

After Run

```
npx expo start --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ... // don't add it here :)
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

CAUTION
**react-native-reanimated/plugin has to be listed last.**